# Data manipulation in multidimension arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an multidimensional array and it contains 5 arrays and each of these 5 arrays contain different number of arrays. For example array at index # 0 contains 99 arrays of same length and array at index # 1 contain 300 arrays of same length. All of these arrays contain combination made from a single array who has 27 elements in it. Now I want to take a single combinations from all five array and get a single multidimensional array of length 5 who has the same number of elements as the original array of 27 elements.

I have tried using for loops but indexing through each of the combination at all 5 places to get an array of 5 arrays whose elements collectively are equal to the original arrays but the amount of iteration are way too much. Is there any better way of doing this.

[image]

Comment: Can you share your multidimensional array simplified and result expected in simplified?

Comment: Each of these 5 arrays contain arrays of same length and these arrays are combination of a single array whose length is 27. I want to take a single combination from each of these 5 arrays to get an array of five elements that has the same elements as the original arrays.  The issue is that if i iterate through each of them by trying different combination of numbers specifying their index, the amount of iteration will get way way to much. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What I'm asking is you to edit the question of your multidimensional array simplified with lesser number of elements and expected results simplified in your question so that we can attend easily

Comment: if your multidimensional array looks like this `[
        [1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9],
    ]` whats your expectation to be?

Comment: @SelakaNanayakkara it has a structure like this [ [ [1,2][1,3],[4,9] ],  [ [5,6,1], [3,1,2], [8,19,10]]]. I want to get array single array from both of these arrays and the elements inside these arrays should be distinct. For example in this case i want to get [[4 ,9],[8,19,10]]. I hope this make sense. TIA!

Comment: What happened to 6 in your provided result array? @Talha Israr

Comment: I assume you missed the values 5 and 6 in the result multi dimensional array. I have provided an answer based upon assumption that you want all distinct values. have a look

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is based on the comment you made** `[ [ [1,2][1,3],[4,9] ], [ [5,6,1], [3,1,2], [8,19,10]]]` **and under the assumption that you want only distinct values only.** **In this case** `[[[4,9]],[[5,6],[8,19,10]]]`

Note: that result subset provide by you does not include 5 and 6 values. Ideally it should be included since it is also distinct.

**Refer the below code :**

```js
function keepDistinctValuesAcrossArrays(arr) {
  const valueOccurrences = new Map();

  // iterate all values and count occurrences of each value
  arr.forEach((subArray) => {
    subArray.forEach((innerArray) => {
      innerArray.forEach((value) => {
        const count = valueOccurrences.get(value) || 0;
        valueOccurrences.set(value, count + 1);
      });
    });
  });

  // Filter values that occur only once (distinct across all arrays)
  const distinctValues = Array.from(valueOccurrences.entries())
    .filter(([value, count]) => count === 1)
    .map(([value]) => value);

  // Filter distinct values in each subarray
  const distinctArrays = arr.map((subArray) => {
    return subArray.map((innerArray) => {
      return innerArray.filter((value) => distinctValues.includes(value));
    });
  });

  // Finally remove out empty arrays if there are any.
  return distinctArrays.map((subArray) => subArray.filter(item => item.length > 0))
  
}

const multiDimArray = [
  [
    [1, 2],
    [1, 3],
    [4, 9],
  ],
  [
    [5, 6, 1],
    [3, 1, 2],
    [8, 19, 10],
  ],
];

const distinctValuesArray = keepDistinctValuesAcrossArrays(multiDimArray);
console.log(JSON.stringify(distinctValuesArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is very similar to Seleka's, but uses things like `reduce` to improve the space efficiency, and avoids `includes` which adds another O(n) to each of those calls.

Also, Seleka and I are interpreting "I want to get array single array from both of these arrays and the elements inside these arrays should be distinct" to mean, distinct in the entire result.  But if you mean "distinct only among its own subArray" that would be a simple change.

Keep in mind that a subArray might not have a combination that has all distinct values, so I'm returning an empty array in that case.

```js
function keepDistinctValuesAcrossArrays(arr) {
  // Object of { [key: number]: number}.  Which represents how many times a number appears in the entire arr.
  const valueOccurences = arr.reduce((valueOccurences, subArray) => {
    subArray.forEach((combination) => {
      combination.forEach((value) => {
        valueOccurences[value] = (valueOccurences[value] || 0) + 1;
      });
    });
    return valueOccurences
  }, {});

  // Return 1 array per subArray which has all distinct values.
  return arr.map((subArray) => {
    return subArray.find(combination => {
      return combination.every(value => valueOccurences[value] < 2);
    }) || []; // return an empty array if none of the combination values have all distinct values
  });
};

const multiDimArray = [
  [
    [1, 2],
    [1, 3],
    [4, 9],
  ],
  [
    [5, 6, 1],
    [3, 1, 2],
    [8, 19, 10],
  ],
];

const distinctValuesArray = keepDistinctValuesAcrossArrays(multiDimArray);
console.log(JSON.stringify(distinctValuesArray));
```

This has an O(n) runtime and O(n) space due to the valueOccurences object.